# compare 2 csv find a match and output it using linux shell

Tags: shell, csv, matching

I am really confused with uniq, sort, awk so ...
got 2 csv

```
tail 300513-code.csv 
11916
11922
11896
11897
128647
1319760
1321176
1017022
1017017
1220901
```

tail 30-05-4UTF.csv

```
131318,"...","st365-3",0,5
1220357,"Ящик алюминиевый зимний",,0,1
,"!!Марко Поло",,,
1014492,"Коробка Марко Поло TF1331D 13.8х7.7х3.1см.","1694.13.31","       16,00",1
1017795,"Ящик Марко Поло FS2000 white-black 2-х полочный 29х16х14см.","1694.20.01","      122,00",5
10923,"Ящик Марко Поло TR2045 red 2-х секционый большой 51.5х39.5х56.5см.","1694.20.45","      351,00",4
10925,"Ящик Марко Поло TR2045 yellow 2-х секционый большой 51.5х39.5х56.5см.","1694.20.47","      351,00",1
12717,"Металоискатель CARRETT",,"     4050,00",1
1319913,"Пакет 50 коп.","01.янв",0,269
17596,"Пакет полиэтиленовый 40х50",1,"        1,00",4843
```

So the first one is a code for which i need to find a match and output only the ones that are matching. Example output.csv

```
12717,"Металоискатель CARRETT",,"     4050,00",1
1319913,"Пакет 50 коп.","01.янв",0,269
17596,"Пакет полиэтиленовый 40х50",1,"        1,00",4843
```

suppose this 3 lines had a match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your given input and output don't match. `12717, 1319913, 17596` I cannot find them in your first file.  I assume they are just example. And I think the following line is what you are looking for, so try this line:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}$1 in a' 300513-code.csv 30-05-4UTF.csv
```

Comment: yes, you are right. That was just for example.I used  awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}$1 in a' 300513-code.csv 30-05-4UTF.csv > new.csv so this gives me all the matches in new.csv, TY very much.

Comment: @Kent you wrote this one-liner blind folded, didn't you? +1

Comment: @Jaypal cp the first part, (without input files), one day you will use it as answer here. :D kidding, I just typed it without testing, since there is nothing to test. This kind of questions were really asked many times.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to link using the first field from each file(bash on linux)

```
join -1 1 -2 1 -t, <(sort -k1,1 -t, 300513-code.csv) 
<(sort -k1,1 -t,  30-05-4UTF.csv)
```